# How to connect to Azure file share from Visial Studio or any other way to LOG my file from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, log4net

I developed a bidding project AND deployed it on Microsoft Azure.Now I
m trying to log my project. I am using LOG4net and using rollingAppender to log all my required log's to a ".txt" file. As I am using an Azure instead of a my own server, I am unable to give a path for the logging file in the web.config

```
    <log4net>
    <appender name="Rollingappender" type="log4net.appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Logs\MyLogfile.txt" />
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="LOG_%date{yyyy-mm.dd}.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="True" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <Maxiumfilesize value="10MB " />
      <maxrollbackups value="5" />
      <staticLogFileName value ="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.layout.patternlayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%logger] %level - %message%newline%exception %username " />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="Rollingappender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

above is the code in web.config file,it would work for local machine.
As I'm deploying through Azure and so i published the whole project in azure and user can access my project from azure.Now what path should i give to log my file? 
,where can i log them? because "`<file value="C:\Logs\MyLogfile.txt" />`" this path wont work any more.
I even tried to create a  storage in Azure FILESHARE, but unable to connect to it.

Comment: what azure service do you use? Azure App Service?

Comment: Yes, I have used " web app" service to deploy my project.

Comment: But I have various kinds of logs...I need a log which stores.txt files and another which stores in a database table.so once I configure diagonistcs lot's application logging to a particular storage ,which is either a blog storage or a table storage I can not configure it to another.I need two kinds of logs in my case.

Comment: replied. see my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

For Azure App Service (Web App or formerly known as Websites), you can enable diagnostic logging which will give you the choice to log to Azure Blob storage, Azure File or Local File.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

RE: But I have various kinds of logs...I need a log which stores.txt files and another which stores in a database table.so once I configure diagonistcs lot's application logging to a particular storage ,which is either a blog storage or a table storage I can not configure it to another.I need two kinds of logs in my case.

In this case, i think you will have to implement your own trace listener.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650498.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396